# Display Modes Letterbox vs Wide-Screen

Tags: terminology

In Skyrim graphical options, what is the difference between `letterbox` mode and `wide-screen` mode? I've seen this in other games as well. Can you view more things in wide-screen mode vs letterbox mode? How should I choose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Letterbox is a way to display a widescreen image (16:9, for example) on a 4:3 monitor without distorting the image to fill the screen, using black borders on the top and bottom of the image to proportion the image correctly.

Widescreen is, like the name suggests, a wide image format (relative to 4:3) that is used in television and gaming.

Unless this is the explanation you were looking for, you might need to be more specific in your question.